# UnitTest frameworks for AS2?

Tags: flash, unit-testing, actionscript-2

I have just tried out [ASUnit](http://blog.thelemur.com/development-procedures/using-asunit) and it wasn't a success,
so I'm looking for something simpler, no need for fancy UI.
trace output is fine.

ASUnit was not a success because it for some strange reason
generated AllTests.as files in all subdirs of /Applications.
I can't figure out how to stop this from happening, so I'm
looking for something simpler. I have done a lot of unit testing
in ruby, c++ and objective c, so its not entirely new to me.

My project is targeted Flash 9 and uses ActionScript 2. 
I work in Flash CS4.

The code that needs testing is math functions, that takes
one or two floating point arguments and returns a floating point value,
so it's well suited for testing.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: now I have written my own test code, here it is. quickndirty.

```
function run_tests(test_function_names:Array):Void {
    trace("running tests");
    var tests_passed:Number = 0;         
    var tests_failed:Number = 0;    
    var tests_total:Number = test_function_names.length;

    for(var i=0; i<tests_total; ++i) {
        var funname = test_function_names[i];
        var fun = this[funname];
        if(typeof fun != 'function') {
            throw("ERROR: " + funname + " is not a function!");
            return;
        }
        trace("testing .... " + funname);
        try {
            fun.call(this);
            tests_passed += 1;
        } catch(msg) {
            trace("ERROR: " + funname + "\n" + msg);
            tests_failed += 1;
        }
    }
    if(tests_failed > 0) {
        trace("" + tests_failed + " of " + tests_total + " tests failed.");
    } else {
        trace("All " + tests_total + " tests executed successfully");
    }
}

public function assert_equal_float(v_expected:Number, v_actual:Number, v_precision:Number) {
    if(v_actual == undefined) {
        throw "v is undefined";
    }
    var v = v_expected - v_actual;
    if(v < 0) v = -v;
    if(v > v_precision) {
        var s1:String = MYUtils.print_r(v_expected);
        var s2:String = MYUtils.print_r(v_actual);
        var s:String = "expected " + s1 + ", but got " + s2;
        throw s.split("\n").join("");
    }
}

public function test_a():Void {
    assert_equal_float(2, 2, 0.01);
}

public function test_b():Void {
    assert_equal_float(2.9999, 3.001, 0.01);
}

public function test_c():Void {
    assert_equal_float(3, 3, 0.01);
}

function run():Void {
    var test_function_names:Array = new Array(
        "test_a",
        "test_b",
        "test_c"
    );
    run_tests(test_function_names)
}
```

output is like this:

```
running tests
testing .... test_a
testing .... test_b
testing .... test_c
All 3 tests executed successfully
```

Comment: out of interest, if your targeting Flash Player 9 and are using CS4 why are you coding in AS2? :)

Comment: Targeting Flash Player 9 is a requirement for the project I'm working on. And it's my first flash project! I don't think its possible to use AS3 with Flash Player 9. It's very difficult to find AS2 documentation, most of the time I bump into Flex, Air, AS3 info. Coming from C to AS, I REALLY miss printf. And no builtin regexp that is terrible! Hopefully AS3 is less painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are not many unit testing frameworks for as2...

I found [as2lib](http://osflash.org/as2lib), homepage is dead, but you can still go to its [API page](http://api.as2lib.org/) and get the code in its [project on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/as2lib)

There is [astuce](http://code.google.com/p/astuce/) too. But its as2 development is stopped.

You may try to port [PerformanceTest from gskinner](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/04/as3_performance.html) to as2 too... :P

Comment: Thank you Andy. Agree, its unfortunate that so many important pages go dead after some years. These projects looks very useful.